# add image to lightSlider using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used angular  to retrieve images from server and show it in slider using lightSlider when add new image to imageList lightSlider not work .

HTML

```
<ul id="Images">
  <image></image>
</ul>
```

Custom directive

```
 var app = angular.module("app");
     app.directive("image", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "./templates/image.html",
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Template

```
<li ng-repeat="i in imageList">
  <img ng-src="{{i}}">
</li>
```

when add new image to imageList lightSlider not work

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass an imageList to your directive. I think your directive is not necessary.

Without a directive you should end up with somthing like this:

```
<ul id="images">
  <li ng-repeat="i in imageList">
    <img ng-src="i">
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- imageList = ['http://www.my-url/image1.jpg', 'http://www.my-url/image2.jpg'] -->
```

When you need the image directive use an isolated scope with the = binding or the > binding (see [angular-documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)